# Kotlin - @hide javadoc equivalent

Tags: kotlin, kdoc

I'm trying to hide a method that should be visible only for test usage.

Is there any equivalent for javadoc's `@hide`

I'm not an expert using KDoc neither JavaDoc, If I'm missing any concept please point me to it.

```
/** @hide */
fun methodToHide() : String = "foo"
```

Comment: If it's available only for test, is it in the src/test/kotlin tree? And thus not built into your normal -src.jar file? If those conventions are followed, dokka won't build the doc files when you direct it to run only over your src/main/kotlin tree.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to show that method/function is not part of public API and is exposed only t obe testable, it's considered to be a good practice to use annotation `@VisibleForTesting`. If you don't have guava or similar library in your project you can create such annotation easiily yourself.